# How To Prevent Leveling Up From Spam For A Python Discord Bot

Tags: python, windows, discord, discord.py, bots

So, recently I've been working on a discord bot in python that levels you up while you talk in a discord server, many popular bots like Carl Bot and MEE6 both have functions like this which I find to be quite interesting; so I wanted to try and recreate it.  The bot works perfectly fine, but it does have a few caveats which I would like to try and have fixed, for one there is no way to check your level or get a leader board for the top 10 people in the server.  But, the issue I want to find and resolve here is the fact that you can spam messages; messages that make no sense and many messages that only need to be one or two.  So, how do I do this, how can I prevent spam in my system for creating this.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import discord
import os
import random
import time

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

#On Ready Event.
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot Ready.")
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Logged In As:  {0.user}".format(client))

#Function For Getting A Users Information And Level Them Up.
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  with open("users.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)

  await update_data(users, member)

  with open("users.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users, f)

#Function For Sending Messages.
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  with open("users.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)

  await update_data(users, message.author)
  await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
  await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

  with open("users.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
  if not str(user.id) in users:
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["experience"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["level"] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exprience):
  users[str(user.id)]["experience"] += exprience

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
  experience = users[str(user.id)]["experience"]
  level_start = users[str(user.id)]["level"]
  level_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

  if level_start < level_end:
    await channel.send(f"{user.mention} Has Leveled Up!  They Have Leveled Up To Level {level_end}!")
    users[str(user.id)]["level"] = level_end

client.run(os.getenv("Token"))
client.run(os.environ["Token"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to ensure that members cannot spam messages and still receive credit is to implore some form of a timing system. To do this, you need to be able to store data. However, you likely won't need a persistent data storage and can use a dictionary.

In this example, I am storing a member's last message in terms of seconds from `time.time()` and checking if their last recorded message timestamp is **less than 60 seconds from now**. This will only allow members to receive credit for their message minutes at a time. Additionally, notice that I only update a member's last message after receiving credit. This ensures that they may still send more than a single message a minute and still receive credit for their messages spaced a minute apart.

```py
from time import time

member_messages = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global member_messages

    current_time = time()
    last_message_requirement = current_time - 60  # Change this cooldown (in seconds) however you like

    if member_messages.get(message.author.id, 0) <= last_message_requirement:
        with open("users.json", "r") as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

        with open("users.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

        member_messages[message.author.id] = current_time
```

Comment: I would recommend using `member_messages.get(key, default_value_if_not_existent)` as it's more concise and readable, but other than that, great answer!

Comment: Agreed, this is an amazing answer!  Thank you so much my man!  :D